# Windows Phone 8.1 MultipartFormDataContent is missing

Tags: c#, silverlight, upload, windows-phone, httpclient

Why can't I use `MultipartFormDataContent` and `StreamContent`?
I am getting the following error:

> The type or namespace name 'MultipartFormDataContent' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Here is my code:

```
var fileUploadUrl = @"http://<IPaddress>:<port>/fileupload";
                var client = new HttpClient();
                photoStream.Position = 0;
                MultipartFormDataContent content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
                content.Add(new StreamContent(photoStream), "file", fileName);
                await client.PostAsync(fileUploadUrl, content)
                    .ContinueWith((postTask) =>
                    {
                        postTask.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to [add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.net.http.multipartformdatacontent%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) the System.Net.Http class

```
using System.Net.Http
```

Comment: I tried: The type or namespace name 'Http' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Net' (are you missing an assembly reference?)